# What is this process/action called in English?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, mathematical-physics, philosophy

it is a fairly generate question regarding a terminology.

People without science or engineering discipline makes an unfounded claim X, but people with such discipline start with proven facts A, B, C, D, and step by step they derive and prove using proven principals, so that what they conclude is mathematically or scientifically sound and without any flaw:

```
From A and B, X is derived

C, D => Y

X, Y => Z
```

What is this process/methodology called generally? Is it called "derive and prove"? I had my Tertiary education in China so I don't know the English terminology for this. Thanks!

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The scientific method perhaps.

Comment: Maybe deduction?

Comment: [Deductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning)

Comment: Or analytic reasoning?

Comment: Or perhaps "logic"?